# How to handle optimistic updates in offlineFirst mode when refetchOnReconnect is set to always

Tags: offline, react-query

I'm having some issues handling the query data when I'm mutating some resource while offline. In my application, I can do both `GET /preferences` and `PUT /preferences`.

My react-query configuration is:

```
const clientConfig = {
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      networkMode: 'offlineFirst',
      retry: 1,
      refetchOnReconnect: 'always'
    },
    mutations: {
      networkMode: 'offlineFirst',
      retry: 1
    }
  }
}
```

The mutate hook is basically their example from the docs:
[Optimistic Updates](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/optimistic-updates)

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()

return useMutation({
  mutationFn: updatePreferences,
  
  onMutate: async (newPreferences) => {
    // Cancel any outgoing refetches
    // (so they don't overwrite our optimistic update)
    await queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ['preferences'] })

    // Snapshot the previous value
    const previousPreferences = queryClient.getQueryData(['preferences'])

    // Optimistically update to the new value
    queryClient.setQueryData(['preferences'], (old) => [...old, newPreferences])

    // Return a context object with the snapshotted value
    return { previousPreferences }
  },
  
  // If the mutation fails,
  // use the context returned from onMutate to roll back
  onError: (err, newPreferences, context) => {
    queryClient.setQueryData(['preferences'], context.previousPreferences)
  },
  
  // Always refetch after error or success:
  onSettled: () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['preferences'] })
  },
})
```

What I think is happening is:

1. app is offline
2. user clicks on a button that calls `useMutation` where I optimistically update the query data inside `onMutate` fn. The app UI gets updated to reflect these new changes. The `PUT /preferences` fails because there is no internet connection so data is not saved.
3. app becomes online
4. `GET /preferences` runs. App UI is updated with the data that exists on the server before updating it.
5. The `PUT` request will run again and is successful. I suppose `cancelQueries` should stop the `GET /preferences` update the query data (from #4) but `onMutate` doesn't run on the second `PUT` request. `onSettled` will now run and if we invalidate the query, this will force a new `GET /preferences` and the UI will update to show the data after the change.

The data that is being displayed goes like:

1. (app offline) show current-data
2. change preferences and click "save". UI shows new-data
3. (app online). `GET /preferences` -> show current-data from #1
4. `PUT /preferences` -> invalidate query -> `GET /preferences` -> show new-data

How can we stop having the UI jump from new data to old data and back to new data? Is there a way to force `onMutate` run again with the same payload and maybe `cancelQueries` will stop the `GET` request to update the query data?

What I find working is if I add `queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ['preferences'] })` before `useMutation`, for example:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()

queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ['preferences'] })

return useMutation({
  mutationFn: updatePreferences,
  onMutate: async (newPreferences) => {
    ...
  },
  onError: {...},
  onSettled: {...}
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution or maybe I can try something else.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty good question, and you've also analyzed the root-cause perfectly. `onMutate` only runs once, so `queryClient.cancelQueries` doesn't take place when the mutation is resumed. When you go online again, the queries and mutations are resumed simultaneously, so it really depends on which is faster.

One way I could think of solving is to stop the `refetchOnReconnect` if you have a mutation queued for that query. This is a bit harder to find out, but all `refetchOn...` flags can also be functions:

```
refetchOnReconnect: (query) => boolean | 'always'
```

so theoretically, you could return `false` if you have a mutation that is either going on or scheduled:

```
refetchOnReconnect: () => {
  return queryClient.isMutating() ? false : 'always'
}
```

Now this code would affect all queries, so you would have to narrow it down to queries that "relate to" your mutations, which is the hard part. But maybe it's also okay to not refetch any query on reconnect if there is any mutation scheduled...